# Jenkins Changes link

Tags: jenkins, version-control

What is the purpose of the "Changes" link in the Jenkins UI?
Can anyone point to the Jenkins documentation that describes the "Changes" link?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When Jenkins pull the source code, it get a new SVN revision or a new Git SHA1.

This link displays the SCM changes since the last build:

[image]

Comment: I did some search and I didn't find any official link :( What do you want to know about this changes functionality?

Comment: I know this is old, but this page bugs me a LOT.  I have a build script repo, and a separate repo for the "real" SW, all in the same Bitbucket project.  Changes made to the build script repo show up in the /changes page when building the "real" SW.